# Can't edit web shortcut Details section (gives access denied on web shortcuts)

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-permissions, file-shortcut

I get "File Access Denied" when I try to edit any web shortcut's "Details" section (e.g. Description or Notes values) and try to save my edits. My account is administrator.

**N.B.** this is a problem that appears for all internet shortcut (.url) files even the newly created ones. I confirmed that the owner is MyUserAccountName and that MyUserAccountName has Full Control access on the file and still the problem exists.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Same here. It tells me I need permission from the user I'm signed into, which signals to me that a process outside my user is involved. So I tried granting full control to Everyone. That didn't help.

Also consistent with your screenshot, mine complains about the parent folder, not the shortcut file. So I tried granting full control over the folder to Everyone, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The Error dialog box suggest that this is a permission issue: next thing to do is thus to verify in the "Security" tab if you have enough permissions to modify the shortcut.

On that same security tab, click on the "Advanced"  button to verify who is the owner of that shortcut.

You may want either to reclaim ownership or add appropriate permissions for your account there.

Comment: This is a problem that's caused for all internet shortcut (.url) files even the newly created ones. I confirmed that the owner is MyUserAccountName and that MyUserAccountName has Full Control access.